# What is this green pipe with an open end sticking out of the ground?

Tags: pipe, vent

I'm looking at an REO property, and I cam across something and have no idea what it is. it appears to be a green pipe pipe in the ground that is open on top. It's on the side of the house, and there is a slight impression in the ground near the pipe .... There is relatively new fuel oil tank in the basement, so perhaps it's where they removed the old one? i really have no idea, but it seems strange and I was just wondering if anyone has an idea[image]

[image]

Comment: figuratively: burried bodies.  Could be anything from radon to exhaust gas to an abandoned drain pipe

Comment: Could you ask the owner, or realtor?

Comment: Septic system or city sanitation? How tall is the pipe relative to the house?

Comment: I cant ask the realtor or owner because it's an REO ( auction property ) and nobody has any idea .... it goes up about another two feet, so 7 feet total and appears to be open on the end ... the house has septic not sewer, and it appears that the sewer pipe exits  on the back of the house rather than this side so I assumed that the tank and leach field was in that direction

Comment: The spot and depression makes me think weeping system or drainage of some kind... But the sewer pipe doesn't make a lot of sense, those are usually short concrete pipes. Is there evidence of former or current downspouts over this pipe?

Comment: I cant see a drain pipe coming from the roof, but I suppose that what it could be thought, it strange that they would use this material ... ill add another pohoto

Comment: I'd say it's conservatively $10,000-20,000 off what you were thinking of bidding, just in case - or simply a red flag to walk away from. Green is typically sewer pipe, but it could be a half-baked radon system. The odd angle bespeaks something not very professional...

Comment: Whatever it is. It is blocking access to the meter enclosure and therefore a code violation. It will have to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try picking it up.

No, really, are you sure it's actually connected from something? It looks like a leftover piece of material that was leaning against the structure until it got kind of stuck in the ground.

Maybe it's a random piece of junk stuck into the ground by another bidder, to trick the current holder into accepting a lower price. If this proves to be the case then you should draw cracks on the windows and bid even lower.

Comment: I did try moving it ... no doubt it's stuck in the ground, I have no idea how deep though. Also there is a slight depression around it, septic vent of some sort would seem likely to me, but the sewer lines exit the structure on the other side, so it does not make sense that the septic tank would be over on the left of the structure

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is a septic vent that was too close to the house, so it was left long to get noxious gases above window height. In my area, vents are typically 3" PVC.